# Why urlfetch can't download HackerNews RSS-feed (DownloadError: ApplicationError: 2)?

Tags: google-app-engine

On March, 13 [www.cliws.com](http://www.cliws.com/) hosted on Google App Engine stopped to fetch HN's RSS feed located at http://news.ycombinator.com/rss

www.cliws.com is RSS-reader like Google Reader but a bit better ;) It regularly checks various RSS-feeds, so from logs I can see exact date when Google stopped to download HN's RSS feed (it worked fine before).

The problematic RSS-feed url is fetched without any issues locally in the development SDK, but can't be downloaded in the production.

Please see bellow demonstration of the problem:

```
s~cliwws> from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
s~cliwws> print urlfetch.fetch('http://news.ycombinator.com/rss').status_code
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/dogada/sources/python/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/urlfetch.py", line 263, in fetch
    return rpc.get_result()
  File "/home/dogada/sources/python/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 592, in get_result
    return self.__get_result_hook(self)
  File "/home/dogada/sources/python/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/urlfetch.py", line 365, in _get_fetch_result
    raise DownloadError(str(err))
DownloadError: ApplicationError: 2 
s~cliwws> print urlfetch.fetch('http://www.osnews.com/feed/kind/News').status_code
200
s~cliwws> print urlfetch.fetch('http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/atom.xml').status_code
200
s~cliwws> print urlfetch.fetch('http://google.com').status_code
200
```

I also filled bug for this issue: 'http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7181'

What are possible reasons for this strange behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing here, but I assume that the web server stopped accepting your requests due to a flagged user agent, IP address or other meta data.

Since you can not influence the outgoing IP on GAE, try setting the user agent to "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.21 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1042.0 Safari/535.21" to test if that changes anything.

Comment: Thanks, @Michael, I already changed User-Agent, Accept-*, Cookie, Referer headers - no effect unfortunately.